# signInWithEmailAndPassword javascript not working [Solved]

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

[Solution]
"The alert() blocks code execution, replace it with console.log() instead. Also, add e.preventDefault() as first line in the function otherwise the form will be submitted (the page would refresh)" – Dharmaraj

I was missing the id attributes in the input elements so the javascript cannot get the values I was typing. Thanks to Dharmaraj's comment, I was able to troubleshoot it.

I'm trying to make a page that allows the user to sign-in. I have watched video tutorials but they combine the sign-in and sign-up in a single page. I want to use a different page to sign-in the user. The javascript works but it does not go inside the signInWithEmailAndPassword function.

My html

```html
<div id="navbar">
        <div class="subhead1">
            <a href="../index.html"><img src="../Images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="subhead2">
            <div>
                <a href="signup.html" class="signup">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="account_type.html" class="login">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>Customer Login</h2>
            </div>
            <form>
                <div class="input">
                    <div class="input-row">
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-row">
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-row">
                        <div class="remember-me">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" value="Remember Me" />
                            <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                        </div>
                        <button id="submitData" name="submitData">Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-row">
                        <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Javascript

```js
<script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-analytics.js";
        import {
            getAuth,
            signInWithEmailAndPassword
        } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-auth.js";


        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "redacted",
            authDomain: "redacted",
            projectId: "redacted",
            storageBucket: "redacted",
            messagingSenderId: "redacted",
            appId: "redacted",
            measurementId: "redacted",
            databaseURL: "redacted"
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const auth = getAuth();

        // Firebase functions

        submitData.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            alert("test");
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    // Signed in 
                    const user = userCredential.user;
                    alert("Success");
                    // ...
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    const errorMessage = error.message;
                    alert("Error");
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The `alert()` blocks code execution, replace it with `console.log()` instead. Also, add `e.preventDefault()` as first line in the function otherwise the form will be submitted (the page would refresh)

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thanks man. Your instructions helped me troubleshoot. I was having troubles checking the console because the page refreshes so I used alert(). 

I lacked the id attribute in the input element so the script cannot get the values I was typing. When I added it in, it worked!

Answer (score -1):

I was missing the id attributes in the input elements so the javascript cannot get the values I was typing. Thanks to Dharmaraj's comment, I was able to troubleshoot it.